# Add comments to Custom node module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In my custom module I would like to add the comments functionality. I've tried a couple of things but didn't workout so far.

```
// render comments form
$output .= theme('my_module_front_page'); 
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $node_good_practice->nid;
$output .= render(drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment));
return $output;
```

The code above puts the comments form to my node page.

But when I fill in the comment form and submit, it redirects me to this page: `comment/reply/node id` and then i have to fill in my comment all over again and the comment isn't saved.

I would like to submit and stay on the same page instead of the redirect. And the comment must be saved after submitting.

Right now, the comment form appears on my node page (custom module template). I enter a comment and click on "Save."
I am sent to `/comment/reply/<node_id>`, but all the comment fields are empty. The comment isn't saved either.

What I would like to happen is:

- Having a comment form on the node page
- Enter a comment
- Click on "Save"
- Drupal saves the comment, and redirect me back to the node/page I was viewing.

### Things I've tried

- Adding Redirect

  ```
  $form['#redirect'] = "/success-stories/".$node_good_practice->good_practice_name."/".$node_good_practice->nid;
  ```

  It did not change anything.
- Changing action

  ```
  $form['#action'] = "/success-stories/".$node_good_practice->good_practice_name."/".$node_good_practice->nid;
  ```

  It redirects me to `node/node_id/#comment-17`
- Use `drupal_build_form()`

  ```
  $info->nid = $node_good_practice->nid;
  $comment['build_info']['args'][0] = $info;
  $comment['redirect'] = "http://www.google.nl";
  $output .= render(drupal_build_form('comment_form', $comment));
  ```

  The form is being displayed, but it does not redirect; it is sent to `comment/reply/node_id`.

Comment: You say the code works and then describe that it doesn't save your comment. Can you specify more clearly what works and what doesn't work?

Comment: I edited the question, is this more clear?

Comment: Unless you don't refer to a specific PHP version, like PHP-5.3 (which I don't think is the case here), just tag as PHP, not PHP5. Thank you!

Comment: It'll probably be to do with [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/form-redirect-not-working-if-destination-is-in-url-drupal-7)

Comment: @Clive - Thanx for the link. I tried out the link but didn't help. Probably because the link describes self created forms in a module and this does not work for the core comments form which i'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the problem was caused by `drupal_build_form` and `drupal_get_form` after submitting a comment. If the $_POST was filled the drupal_build_form and the drupal_get_form functions redirects met to `/node/node_id/#comment-17` or to `/comment/reply/<node_id>`
So i unset the SESSION before loading the form and the problem was fixed.

So the solution from Mike only works when you unset the SESSION. But he has been verry helpfull.

So now i have:

```
if(isset($_POST['form_id'])) {
  $comment = new stdClass();
  $comment->nid = $good_practice_id; // Node Id the comment will attached to
  $comment->name = $user->name;
  $comment->status = 1;
  $comment->language = "und";
  $comment->subject = $_POST['subject']; 
  $comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['value'] = $_POST['comment_body'][$node_good_practice->language][0]['value'];
  $comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; 
  comment_submit($comment);
  comment_save($comment);
  unset($_POST);
} 

$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $node_good_practice->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $node_good_practice);
$form['#action'] = url('success-stories/'.$node_good_practice->good_practice_name.'/'. $comment->nid);

$output .= theme('good_practices_front_detail_page', array('oGoodPractice' => $oGoodPractice, 'aGoodPractices' => $aGoodPractices, 'aComments' => $aComments, 'oSectors' => $oSectors, 'oCountries' => $oCountries, 'links' => $aLinks));
$output .= render($form);
$output .= theme('pager', array('tags'=>array()));

return $output;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a custom module, you could alter the comment_form using the [form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) hook for your specific cases. You can set the form to only use your modules submit function. Then in your custom submit function, you submit the comment to the comment module for saving (calling the [comment_form_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form_submit/7) function), and then do the redirect back to the node yourself.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<?php
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){
        if ($form_id == 'comment_form' && isset($form['#node']) && ($form['#node']->type == 'mynodetype')){
            $form['#submit'] = array('mymodule_comment_form_submit');
        }
    }

    function mymodule_comment_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
        module_load_include('module','comment');
        comment_form_submit($form,$form_state);
        $url = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$form['#node']->nid);
        header('Location: '.$url, TRUE);
        drupal_exit($url);
    }
```

In your template file, still build the comment form the way you are:

```
$info->nid = $node_good_practice->nid;
$comment['build_info']['args'][0] = $info;
$output .= render(drupal_build_form('comment_form', $comment));
```

This solution may seem a bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: unfortunately it is still redirecting to /comment/reply/<node_id> But youre idea seems right. I will troubleshoot further and see where it goes wrong. I will let you know soon.

Comment: interesting, because the drupal_goto should take the user back to the node page.  I wonder if a function is being triggered within comment_form_submit (or rather a function it invokes) that is causing the redirect.

Comment: @Mike `drupal_goto()` will ignore what you pass to it if there is a `destination` query parameter in the URL. I'm pretty sure Drupal adds such a parameter to the comment reply form links so that might be the problem

Comment: @Clive you are right, just looked at the documentation for drupal_goto and it will use the destination path if present as a get variable.  Jurgo, I have updated my code so that it'll use the php header() along with drupal_exit(), so that you do not have to worry about the destination.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be the answer?

```
$comment->nid = $row->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
$form['#redirect'] = 'CHANGE_VIEWSPAGE_HERE?page=' . (int)$_GET['page'];
print render($form);
```

can't try it myself sorry. I found it at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/d7-comment-form-doesnt-submit

Comment: Thanx for the answer. However the redirect option did not make any change to the result.